# How to sort two dimentional array with string based on length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two dimentional array and i wan to sort in on order and based on string length. how can i do it? this is my code:

```js
arr = [['ab',0],['ax',0],['ac',0],['bsd',0],['ad',0],['asd',0],['bd',0],['ay',0]];
function sortByLen(a,b){
   return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}
arr.sort(sortByLen);
console.log(arr);
```

i want it to become in this order

```
["ab", 0]
["ac", 0]
["ad", 0]
["ax", 0]
["ay", 0]
["bd", 0]
["asd", 0]
["bsd", 0]
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a single sort with a callback which respects the length of the first item of the inner arrays with using the difference of the length. If the length is equal take [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for sorting by alphabet.

```js
var array = [['ab', 0], ['ax', 0], ['ac', 0], ['bsd', 0], ['ad', 0], ['asd', 0], ['bd', 0], ['ay', 0]];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[0].length - b[0].length || a[0].localeCompare(b[0]);
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
var arr = [['ab',0],['ax',0],['ac',0],['bsd',0],['ad',0],['asd',0],['bd',0],['ay',0]];

var sorted = arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a > b
  }).sort(function(a,b) {
     return a[0].length - b[0].length
  })

console.log('sorted',sorted)
```

Comment: double sorting is one too much, because the second does not respect the first sorting.

Comment: The second sort is applied on the the array that is sorted alphabetically. Although my answer is more readable, your answer gives better performance!

Comment: not really, because [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is not stable and another sort destroys the last sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Check if lengths differ. If they do, sort by them. If equal, sort alphabetically:

```
var arr = [['ab',0],['ax',0],['ac',0],['bsd',0],['ad',0],['asd',0],['bd',0],['ay',0]];
function sortByLen(a,b){
   if(a[0].length < b[0].length) return -1;
   if(a[0].length > b[0].length) return 1;
   if(a[0] < b[0]) return -1;
   if(a[0] > b[0]) return 1;
   return 0;
}
arr.sort(sortByLen);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
arr = [['ac',0],['ab',0],['ax',0],['bsd',0],['ad',0],['asd',0],['bd',0],['ay',0]];

const sortedItems = arr
  .sort((a, b) => a[0] > b[0])
  .sort((a, b) => a[0].length > b[0].length)

console.log(sortedItems)
```

Comment: double sorting is one too much, because the second does not respect the first sorting.